# Edittext error text is truncated vertically on Samsund Devices

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am setting error on an edit test in android however text is cutting from half vertically. I have tried every solutions available online. Image is attached herewith.

[image]

Here is the xml code.

```
<FrameLayout
        style="@style/FormRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl1"
            style="@style/FormLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/First_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/personal_first_name"
            style="@style/FormValue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:cursorVisible="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And the styles:

```
    <style name="FormValue">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FormLabel">
    <item name="android:textColor">#212531</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FormRow">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">9dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">9dp</item>
    <item name="android:animateLayoutChanges" tools:targetApi="11">true</item>
</style>
```

On nexus 4,5 there is no issue but on samsung devices (s4, omega) I am facing this issue.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share the layout for your error box and your form screen ??

Comment: Maybe your edittext or layout has margin values. Check it.

Comment: Please share your XML Code.

Comment: Code has been added into question

Comment: shouldn't that be `<item name="**android:paddingRight**">100dp</item>` in your style named = "FormValue".. .i have no access to ide currently,so haven't tested it yet..just a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last got the root case. Actually all of my EditText was extended by the a base edit text class. In constructor my custom edit text I was wrapping the context into a style. Even though there was no problem in the style. Have a look.

```
public BaseEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Textbox),attrs); //This cuts the error in half vertical
}
```

And the style

```
<style name="Textbox" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
   <item name="android:textColor">#5f5f5f</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
   <item name="android:textColorHint">#999999</item>
    .....

</style>
```

So what I have done is, just don't wrap the context with style and add all attributes with the code.

```
 public BaseEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context,attrs);

        setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        setLines(1);
        setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#5f5f5f"));
        ...
 }
```

This just fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

i removed tools:targetApi="11" in styles and i checked edittext in code :

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(firstName.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                firstName.setError("Enter FirstName");
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps you